# Use Python to import MXDs into an ArcGIS Pro Project and add the MXD file name to the imported maps

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

The method of importing an MXD to an ArcGIS Pro project has already been asked as [Importing MXD to ArcGIS Pro programmatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169008) and it goes like this:

```
workspaceMXD = r'FOLDER CONTAINING MXDS'
projectsArea = r'C:ArcGIS\Projects'
APRX_name = 'ArcGIS Project.aprx'
output_APRX = os.path.join(projectsArea, APRX_name)


# Variables
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
arcpy.env.workspace = workspaceMXD

# List files in workspaceMXD
listFiles = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

# Import MXD Files
for files in listFiles:
  # file names in list appended to folder path
  inputMXD = os.path.join(workspaceMXD, files)
  print (inputMXD)
  aprx.importDocument(inputMXD)
  aprx.saveACopy(output_APRX)
```

This results in a folder of MXD's being imported into an ArcGIS Pro Project - however, these imported maps are named according to their data frame name (e.g. Layers).

How can you access the MXD filename and include it as a variable in the aprx.importDocument class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: "you can't **reliably do this** with the functions that are available."

The longer answer is: "you **can** do this if you allow your code to make some assumptions".

The [ArcGISProject](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm) class as you point out allows you to import a MXD.
The [Map](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) class allows you to read and **write** the map name.

The following code, based on your starting code will:

- Find all MXDs in a folder
- import each MXD into the project
- Immediately after importing the MXD it'll:
- > Assume the map that has been loaded was called **Layers**
- > Change the name of that map to the file name of the MXD.

If the Dataframe in the MXD was NOT "Layers", it will NOT rename the newly imported map, and the code will bail out when trying to rename the map. You could try/except it, but now you run the risk that the code will identify the wrong map as you'll have 2 or more maps that have not been renamed. The logic (and flaw) of this code is it assumes there is only 1 map in the project named Layers and assumes it can rename *that* map to the MXD file name.

```
import os
mxdDir =r"C:\data\mxds"
arcpy.env.workspace = mxdDir
mxds = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
mxds
> ['mxd1.mxd', 'mxd22.mxd', 'mxd33.mxd']
prj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
for m in mxds:
    print("Importing {} ".format(m))
    prj.importDocument(os.path.join(mxdDir, m))
    pMap = prj.listMaps("Layers")[0]
    pMap.name = m.split(".mxd")[0]
> Importing mxd1.mxd
> Importing mxd22.mxd
> Importing mxd333.mxd
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks